# Java Swing table Row

Tags: java, swing

Java Swing questions are on the table.
This is to add the Row Data 10ea continue as long as the output vertically.
I do this rather than lengthwise, then add Row I want to take.

Do not do this like below

```
----- A ---------- B -----
     Data1
     Data2
        .
        .
        .
     Data10
     Data1
        .
        .
        .
     Data10
-------------------------
```

I want to like this one.

```
----- A ---------- B -----
    Data1        Data1
    Data2        Data2
    Data3        Data3
    Data4        Data4
    Data5        Data5
    Data6        Data6       
    Data7        Data7
    Data8        Data8
    Data9        Data9
    Data10       Data10
```

Comment: Not sure if you want the second column under B?

Comment: Yes, my description of it.

Answer (score 0):

A i understood, you need to set every 10 data inputs to the new column. 
IMO the easiest way is to make counter tnat will add 1 more row to your table and drop to zero after 10th item comes.
Something like this:

```
int t = 0;
while(your inputs){
   int i=0;
   if (i==10){
      t++;
      DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
      model.setRowCount(t+1);
      table.setModel(model);
      i=0;
   }
   table.setValueAt(yourValue,i,t);
   i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, so Here's how I make two columns of data. Without knowing how many rows initially, I just set the column names and then add the rows later

```
String[] columnNames = {"A", "B"};

DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
JTable table = new JTable(model);

while (data has next){
    Object someData1 = (Data1);

    Object[] data = {someData1, someData1};

    model.addRow(data);    
}
```